# Loop through list and variable in Ansible

Tags: loops, ansible

I'm going to grant privileges on two MySQL databases to user from to different IP's using Ansible. What I've got now:
Vars:

```
#users
root_user: 'root'
root_password: 'root'
prosody_user: 'prosody'
prosody_password: 'prosody'

#databases
oauth_db: "oauth"

#hosts
prosody_hosts: ['10.0.1.4', '10.0.1.5']
```

Task:

```
- name: add or update mysql user prosody
  mysql_user:
   name: "{{ prosody_user }}"
   host: "{{ item.host }}"
   password: "{{ prosody_password }}"
   login_user: "{{ root_user }}"
   login_password: "{{ root_password }}"
   check_implicit_admin: yes
   append_privs: yes
   priv: "{{ item.database }}.*:ALL,GRANT"
  with_items:
  - { host: "{{ prosody_hosts[0] }}", database: "{{ oauth_db }}" }
  - { host: "{{ prosody_hosts[1] }}", database: "{{ oauth_db }}" }
  - { host: "{{ prosody_hosts[0] }}", database: "{{ prosody_db }}" }
  - { host: "{{ prosody_hosts[1] }}", database: "{{ prosody_db }}" }
```

Direct calling of array elements doesn't look very nice. I just want loop through *prosody_hosts* array in *with_item* directive, сonsidering that *database* is not an array.

Goal is to to get something like this:

```
... 
with_items
- { host: "{{ prosody_hosts }}", database: "{{ oauth_db }}" }  
- { host: "{{ prosody_hosts }}", database: "{{ prosody_db }}" }
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

What you need is nested loops.
See this [Ansible documentation](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_loops.html#nested-loops).

Basically you'd end up with something similar like this. Put your databases in a list called 'databases' like you did with hosts. This will execute the task for every host and every database.
 I haven't tested this but it should get pretty close.

```
- name: add or update mysql user prosody
  mysql_user:
   name: "{{ prosody_user }}"
   host: "{{ item[0] }}"
   password: "{{ prosody_password }}"
   login_user: "{{ root_user }}"
   login_password: "{{ root_password }}"
   check_implicit_admin: yes
   append_privs: yes
   priv: "{{ item[1] }}.*:ALL,GRANT"
  with_nested:
    - "{{ prosody_hosts }}"
    - "{{ databases }}"
```